# Download file from Google Drive via HTTP GET request

Tags: http, curl, request, google-drive-api, wget

Please help me. How I can get a file from Google Drive via HTTP GET request (using wget/curl/postman/etc)?

What I need? File ID, access token and what? How correctly write this HTTP request?

Thanks!

Comment: You can download files on Google Drive using Drive API. When you use Drive API, access token is required. The detail information of Download and Access token are [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) and [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), respectively.

Comment: I tryed it. But I get error "File not found"

Comment: About the detail information that you have tried, can you show us them? If you can show them, please add to your question using EDIT button. Much information helps many user think of the solution.

Comment: Instructions are at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get
You can use the form on the right to try it, and use the Chrome Dev Console to capture the http request to a curl command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @pinoyyid!

> Instructions are at developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get
>   You can use the form on the right to try it, and use the Chrome Dev
>   Console to capture the http request to a curl command